# Template in Rcpp

Tags: templates, rcpp

This cpp function works i pure cpp but in Rcpp. return the following error:

***'T' was not declared in this scope.***

Is that because of tempalte?
Anyone can come with a suggestion?
?

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]


template < typename T>
std::pair<bool, int> findInVector(const std::vector<T>  & vecOfElements, const T  & element)
{
  std::pair<bool, int > result;
  // Find given element in vector
  auto it = std::find(vecOfElements.begin(), vecOfElements.end(), element);
  if (it != vecOfElements.end())
  {
    result.second = distance(vecOfElements.begin(), it);
    result.first = true;
  }
  else
  {
    result.first = false;
    result.second = -1;
  }
  return result;
} 



/*** R
findInVector(c('A', 'b', 'g'), 'g')
*/
```

Comment: It's a FAQ:  Function interfaces to be callied from R can only be `SEXP` types, or types that Rcpp can map to SEXPs.  That excludes templates.

Answer (score 2):

You can't export a templated C++ function with Rcpp.  You need to declare your templated function, and then use a "wrapper" function to handle specific instances of desired types.  For instance:

````
template < typename T>
Rcpp::List findInVector(const std::vector<T>& vecOfElements, const T& element) {

    // Find given element in vector
    auto it = std::find(vecOfElements.begin(), vecOfElements.end(), element);
    if (it != vecOfElements.end()) {
        return Rcpp::List::create(
            Rcpp::Named("result.first") = true,
            Rcpp::Named("result.second") = distance(vecOfElements.begin(), it)
        );
    }
    return Rcpp::List::create(
        Rcpp::Named("result.first") = false,
        Rcpp::Named("result.second") = -1
    );
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List Rcpp_findInVector(const std::vector<std::string>& vecOfElements, const std::char& element) {
    return Rcpp_findInVector(vecOfElements, element);
}

```{R}
Rcpp_findInVector(c('A', 'b', 'g'), 'g')
```
````

R supports fewer types than C++, and as a result generally functions in C++ can simply be spelled out in primitive types that are supported by R rather than using templates (i.e. double, int, bool, char, string)

Comment: Your return object is still not compatible with a `SEXP`.  "Everything" has to become `SEXP .Call(func,  SEXP a, SEXP b, ....)`.  You _could_ make your return object an `Rcpp::List` with the two slots, just return a single (mappable) object.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel ah yes indeed, doh, edited to use `Rcpp::List` which is definitely useful in this case